# CocoaLumberjack with Swift - Calling preprocessor macros

Tags: ios, swift, logging, cocoalumberjack

I started to build an IOS app with the new programming language Swift. I managed to use CocoaPods and was able to successfully create the DDTTYLogger with my CustomLoggerFormatter (Objective-C) in my AppDelegate.swift and append it to the loggers.

```
var customLoggerFormatter = CustomLoggerFormatter()

var consoleLogger: DDTTYLogger = DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance()
consoleLogger.setLogFormatter(customLoggerFormatter)
DDLog.addLogger(consoleLogger)
```

But the problem is, that the CocoaLumberjack Library is using *preprocessor macros* for the logger methods like `DDLogVerbose(@"..")`

Which is defined in the DDLog.h:

```
#define DDLogVerbose(frmt, ...) LOG_OBJC_MAYBE(LOG_ASYNC_VERBOSE, LOG_LEVEL_DEF, LOG_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0, frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Is there any workaround to make preprocessor defines work in Swift? Or did anyone try something similar with more success?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, I just found a solution. Writing an Objective-C Wrapper class calling the preprocessors and offering methods to call it.

Hopefully this will help other people facing the same issues.

I first created a header file:

```
@interface DDLogWrapper : NSObject
+ (void) logVerbose:(NSString *)message;
+ (void) logError:(NSString *)message;
+ (void) logInfo:(NSString *)message;
@end
```

With the corresponding implementation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DDLogWrapper.h"

// Logging Framework Lumberjack
#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDASLLogger.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"

// Definition of the current log level
#ifdef DEBUG
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
#else
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_ERROR;
#endif

@implementation DDLogWrapper

+ (void) logVerbose:(NSString *)message {
    DDLogVerbose(message);
}

+ (void) logError:(NSString *)message {
    DDLogError(message);
}

+ (void) logInfo:(NSString *)message {
    DDLogInfo(message);
}

@end
```

Important is to add the DDLogWrapper.h File to the ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h file and then you are able to instantiate in Swift the DDLogWrapper and call the methods `logVerbose, logError, logInfo.`.

With the following code I was able to make a log statement:

```
DDLogWrapper.logVerbose("TEST");
```

Comment: How do you define the `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`? I tried `#import <DDLogWrapper.h>` and Xcode is complaining `file not found` error. `DDLogWrapper.h` is in directory `ProjectName/Application/DDLogWrapper.h`. I also tried `Application/DDLogWrapper.h` and that didn't work. My `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER` field in `Build Settings` is blank but I have no problems bridging other modules.

Comment: Per an attempted edit by [runios](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3944596/runios), you also need `#import "DDLogMacros.h"`.

Comment: [CocoaLumberjack supports Swift & Objective-C](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack#swift-version-via-cocoapods) if you're migrating your app. 

`pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'`

Requires iOS8 minimum. If you're stuck supporting iOS7 like me then this works a treat.

Answer (score 6):

As of `2.0.0beta4`, CocoaLumberJack includes a `CocoaLumberJack.swift` file that makes its integration with Swift projects really easily.

They use a global var `defaultDebugLevel` to set the `DDLogLevel`, and you can swift basic precompile macros to customize it to your needs.

```
#if DEBUG
    defaultDebugLevel = DDLogLevel.All
#else
    defaultDebugLevel = DDLogLevel.Warning
#endif

DDLog.addLogger(DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance())
DDLogDebug("Debug")
DDLogInfo("Info")
DDLogWarn("Warning")
DDLogVerbose("Verbose")
DDLogError("Error")
```

Comment: I use cocoapods 0.36.0.beta.2 and lumberjack 2.0.0-rc. I have the swift file in Pods ▸ CocoaLumberjack ▸ Classes ▸ CocoaLumberjack.swift. In the swift file in my project, I try to import it but I get `No such module 'CocoaLumberjack'`, ideas?

Comment: lumberjack 2.1.0 now has swift 2.0 support supposedly.

Answer (score 5):

I created a [Swift wrapper for CocoaLumberjack](https://gist.github.com/stigi/505a1b036d4776e4bfe1) that encapsulates everything nicely.

```
DDLog.addLogger(DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance())
DDLog.logLevel = .Info

logInfo("Info")
logWarn("Warn")
logDebug("Debug")
logError("Error")
```