# what is the equivalent to DLog in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, debugging

Sorry if the question has been answered already, but i couldnt find the answer here. In objective-C, it is very helpful to put DLog in the code. what is the same in Swift?

Comment: See if you can find it here : [CocoaLumberjack with Swift - Calling preprocessor macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144404/cocoalumberjack-with-swift-calling-preprocessor-macros)

Comment: thanks i will check this link